# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RegisterService (?).Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the RegisterModule context

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, nest-api

I am facing this problem in nestjs.Project structure is like-

```
src-
    -RegisterModule
       -register.controller.ts
       -register.service.ts
       -register.dto.ts
       -register.schema.ts
       -register.module.ts

    -app.module.ts
    -app.controller.ts
    -app.service.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yaa....I got the solution in just 2 simple steps**

1. Import `MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Register', schema: registrationSchema }])` in registerModule's  import section
2. Import registerModule in appModule